# How do I bevel a merged mesh?

Tags: mesh, bevel

I have a mesh that I merged with CTRL+j, but when I enter edit mode there is still a seam and when I bevel it this happens:

[image: screenshot of the problem]

How can I get it to do something like this at the vertex?

[image: image of goal]

[image: current setup]

Here is the seam I was talking about:

[image: screenshot of problem from further away]

Comment: Yeah i have this problem as well, or when i try to bevel it, it just bevels a really small bit with high polys...

Comment: Attach your file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for detail inspection